# Removing image background in UIImageView at runtime

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a ball assigned to a UIImageView in Interface Builder.  An IBOutlet from the UIImageView is wired to a corresponding UIViewController.  The image has a white background.  When I assign it to the UIImageView in IB, the background is transparent.  In IB, I have the UIImageView set to a transparent background and aspect fill.

When I assign the UIImageView an image at runtime:

```
self.ball.image = ballImage; //ballImage is a UIImage
self.ball.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.ball.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

the UIImageView square has a white background where the ball doesn't display.  Meaning all four corners.  What is the difference that the IB version doesn't show a white background at runtime and the programmatic version does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you set `self.ball.opaque = NO;` in addition to setting the background color to clear. Otherwise, a white background will still be drawn. I believe you have to set both of these whether you use IB or Xcode to create the view - but IB may have set them both for you.

Comment: Thanks on both suggestions. My fault.  There was a PNG version of the JPGs that had transparent backgrounds.  IB was using the PNGs while I was using the JPGs programmatically.  Ugh! However, if the image doesn't have a transparent background, there isn't much you can do about it in an easy way.  Opaque doesn't change it.  I also tried setting opacity by including Quartz framework and self.ball.layer.opacity = 0.0f; but a no go again.  Modifying the image is the easiest route.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to remove background programmatically you may refer to ["Bitmap Images and Image Masks"](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHBCGB) guide. I have no other idea on this point...just using CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors.

In case your *.PNG (or any graphic resource file) doesn't have built-in transparency (just white background) but with IB it looks like transparent - may be *alpha* property less then 1 for your UIImageView and you see partially transparent image.